# CakePHP 3 implementedEvents config array overwrite issue

Tags: events, cakephp-3.0

Here's sample code:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController
    {
        ...
        public function implementedEvents()
        {
            return [
                'Auth.logout' => 'afterLogout'
            ];
        }

        public function afterLogout($event)
        {
            $this->Flash->toast(__('Good bye!'));
        }
        ...
    }
```

Before implementing `implementedEvents()` method, `AppController::beforeRender()` method was triggered properly.
I needed to listen to `Auth.logout` event, so wrote `implementedEvents()` method. I thought it would be merged to the default events array. But after that, `AppController::beforeRender()` stopped working. It didn't trigger any more. So I guess there's an overwriting behavior.

Is this a default behavior of CakePHP 3? And is this an intended behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the intended behavior, as otherwise it would be complicated to overwrite instead of merging.

If you need to merge possible parent listener configuration, then you need to do that on your own, like

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Auth.logout' => 'afterLogout'
    ] + parent::implementedEvents();
}
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is there any way to make some public methods non-actions in controller class?

Comment: @clthck That would be something for a new question... anyways, you can override [`Controller::isAction()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_isAction). It's best to avoid running into that situation in the first place though.

Comment: I need to listen to `Auth.logout` event with `UsersController::afterLogout` method. Obviously it should be public method, but it shouldn't be an action that's accessible from browser. Isn't this case useful? Anyway, thanks for your answer. I never thought about overriding `isAction`.

Comment: @clthck I wouldn't use the term "useful", but maybe "legitimate". And whether that's a legitimate usecase depends on what exactly `afterLogout` does. If it's not controller related, then I'd choose a different implementation, like a custom listener object for example. But again, that's kinda offtopic ;)