# Auth.afterIdentify is not firing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to change something in the user session after it was started. This is temporary, so using an event such as [`Auth.afterIdentify`](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) is what I'm looking for.

### What I tried

- I have largely referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465450/cakephp-3-x-updating-user-data/41476229#41476229) on how to even approach this.
- I have tried [using an anonymous function callback](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-anonymous-listeners) as well as a controller callback method
- Following the [`Auth.afterIdentify`](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) documentation I have added `implementedEvents`
- Made sure `implementedEvents` [has a  `+ parent::implementedEvents()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202526/cakephp-3-implementedevents-config-array-overwrite-issue/35203170#35203170), otherwise the controller kept showing me the home page

### What I have

Here's my current `src/Controller/AppController.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller implements \Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        // …

        $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
        // Trying with an anonymous function
        \Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on('Auth.afterIdentify', function ($event) {
            Log::write( // noticed when posting this question, should have thrown an error
                'info',
                'Testing: ' . $event->getSubject()->id
            );
            debug($event);exit;
        });
        // Trying a controller callback
        \Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on('Auth.afterIdentify', [$this, 'afterIdentify']);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->set('myAuth', $this->Authentication->getResult());
        $this->set('myUser', $this->Authentication->getIdentity());
    }

    public function afterIdentify(CakeEvent $cakeEvent, $data, $auth) {
        debug([
            '$cakeEvent' => $cakeEvent,
            '$data' => $data,
            '$auth' => $auth,
        ]);exit;
    }

    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Auth.afterIdentify' => 'afterIdentify',
        ] + parent::implementedEvents();
    }

}
```

### What doesn't work

It seems neither of the above event listeners is being called. No CakePHP logs are being updated (not even with errors), although they normally work.

### What I expected to happen

- Calling `Log::write` without declaring where it comes from should have thrown (and logged) an error
- The `debug()` information was not displayed
- Removing the `public function afterIdentify` method should have caused an error; it didn't – meaning the controller isn't even looking for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the old auth component and the new authentication plugin, the `Auth.afterIdentify` event belongs to the former.

The authentication plugin's authentication component has a [`Authentication.afterIdentify`](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authenticators.html#events) event, but this only applies to authenticators that are stateful and do not implement automatic persisting. So out of the box this only applies to the `Form` authenticator, and the event is being triggered once on the request where the user was authenticated via the form, on subsequent requests where they are authenticated via for example the `Session` authenticator, the event is not being triggered.

```php
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    // ...

    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');

    $this->Authentication->getEventManager()->on(
        'Authentication.afterIdentify',
        function (
            \Cake\Event\EventInterface $event,
            \Authentication\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface $provider,
            \Authentication\IdentityInterface $identity,
            \Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface $service
        ) {
            // ...
            
            $identity['foo'] = 'bar';
            $this->Authentication->setIdentity($identity);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: As always, thank you! Quick questions: **1.** `Authentication.afterIdentify ` won't be fired if I [e.g. log in as another user programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352326/cakephp-3-login-as-wtih-multiple-auth-sessions)? **2.** If the authentication has been moved out into [cakephp/authentication](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication), is [/4.2/namespace-Cake.Auth.html](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/namespace-Cake.Auth.html) expected to sunset?

Comment: @aexl **1)** It won't (if it would, then the shown example would cause an infinite loop), the event is fired in the component's `beforeFilter()` callback. **2)** Yes, the old auth component is already deprecated, and will be removed in CakePHP 5.0.

Comment: Looks like the docs for the event actually exist, but the borked book  search doesn't find it if you only search for `afterIdentify` :/

Comment: Google seems to find the docs, but the other problem with them is they [have no mention](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authenticators.html#events) of the `Authentication.logout` event, which [was actually implemented](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/pull/127). Either way, no big deal, searching around still helps, so I got my answers :) Thanks again for your help!